# Scoped lifetime services become singletons when injected through controllers

Tags: c#, .net-core, service, lifetime

I have a controller in a .NET Core application:

```
public FriendsController(IFriendRepository friendRepository)
        {
            this.friendRepository= friendRepository;
        }
```

The IFriendRepository is an interface which is implemented with the class:

```
public class FriendRepository : IFriendRepository {
...
}
```

In Startup I set it up by using the following line in ConfigureServices() :

```
services.AddScoped<IFriendRepository , FriendRepository >();
```

However, when the controller is used, FriendRepository is has the lifetime set as a singleton instead of scoped. The reason I was able to find was on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Under Service lifetimes, Scoped. It shows:

[image]

I do not understand how to use Invoke instead of a constructor. The example they use is for a custom middleware, which I at least can't wrap my head on how to interpret it for a constructor.

```
public class FriendRepository : IFriendRepository
    {
        private readonly ManagementDbContext dbContext;

        public FriendRepository(ManagementDbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public void Add(Friend friend)
        {
            this.dbContext.Friends.Add(friend);
        }
        public void Remove(Friend friend)
        {
            this.dbContext.Remove(friend);
        }


        public void Update(Friend friend)
        {
            this.dbContext.Update(friend);
        }
    }
```

The following is "GetFriends", inside FriendRepository:

```
public async Task<QueryResult<Friend>> GetFriendsAsync(FriendQuery queryObj)
        {
            var result = new QueryResult<Friend>();

            var query = dbContext.Friends
                        .Include(c => c.Type)
                        .AsQueryable();

            if(queryObj.TypeId.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(c => c.Type.Id == queryObj.TypeId);
            }

            if(queryObj.Name != null && queryObj.Name.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(queryObj.Name));
            }

            // todo add total price here
            var columnsMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Calculation, object>>>()
            {
                ["id"] = c => c.Id,
                ["name"] = c => c.Name,
                ["type"] = c => c.Type,
                ["totalFriends"] = c => c.TotalFriends,
                ["createdTime"] = c => c.CreatedTime
            };
            query = query.ApplyOrdering(queryObj, columnsMap);

            result.TotalItems = await query.CountAsync();

            query = query.ApplyPaging(queryObj);

            result.Items = await query.ToListAsync();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify "FriendRepository is used has the lifetime set as a singleton"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I fixed it by removing "is used" So, when I have the dependency injection through the Constructor of the controller, even though it should be scoped, as I declare it in Startup.cs, the instance of IFriendRepository, which is set to be FriendRepository has lifetime singleton As it says in the microsoft docs:


public class FriendsController: Controller
    {
        private IFriendRepository friendRepository;

        public CalculationsController(IFriendRepository friendRepository)
        {
            this.friendRepository= friendRepository;
        }

Comment: Also in addition to @AlexeiLevenkov question - controller is not a middleware, so this warning has nothing to do with your code in question.

Comment: @GuruStron I understand, but this seemed to be the only explanation why I got the same repository in multiple requests. Is there any other one?

Comment: @Bbit how do you check it's lifetime?

Comment: So you put breakpoint into constructor of `FriendRepository` and it only called once? I seriously doubt that... but without real [MCVE] there is no way to know what is going on (and what you possibly misinterpret)

Comment: @GuruStron Currently, when I have two separate requests trying to make a call to the same controller, I get an error that the connection is already in use, I don't have it copy pasted at hand, but after googling, that's what I was told was the best explanation. Didn't think of any other way to check lifetime, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Bbit it does not prove your suggestion, TBH.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if I put a breakpoint, the problem doesn't really occur, since the application is frozen so I can't really make the second request. Do you have any pro suggestion, should I log in a file in the constructor. I can make a minimal code example, I was simply hoping that this was something obvious that I had missed since I'm new to .net

Comment: @GuruStron are there any other possible things this could be caused by? I admit I went with the first answer I got when I asked about what could be the issue, I was told that it seemed closest to the problem middleware has.

Comment: ??? You hit breakpoint, investigate things and let app/site to run... If setting breakpoint alone causes app/site to stop you have other problems to solve first...

Comment: @Bbit if your breakpoint in `FriendRepository` constructor is hit multiple times it is a solid proof that `FriendRepository` is not a singleton and problem is somewhere else. Please show the whole `FriendRepository` class, or at least constructor and fields.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did not mean to imply that the application stops when I said "freezes" . What I meant is that the first request is made, I pause. I then continue, the next request is made, but now the first one has been fully finished, so I don't get an error that the connection to the db is already in use. If this sounds too weird with not enough information, never mind, tomorrow I'll either make a minimal example or restart debugging from scratch again. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @GuruStron I've added the class to the question without specific logic, only with the field, constructor and a few basic functions.

Comment: @GuruStron I will check now if my constructor gets hit multiple times again, I honestly can't remember 100% if that is the case, it's a bit late here.

Comment: How `ManagementDbContext` is registered?

Comment: @GuruStron with the following line in ConfigureServices:  services.AddDbContext<ManagementDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

Comment: Basically you are saying that you debugged the site and confirmed that `FriendRepository` is created per-request... yet the question imply that somehow it is created only once... This is why we require [MCVE] for debugging questions - there is no point relying on authors words to describe what is happening... (99% is your actual connection object is static field and none of that DI stuff has any impact on it)

Comment: @GuruStron I ran the project again, this is the error I get when I simply run the application : "InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext". I am yet to see if the constructor runs multiple times. Will check that next.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov as I said before to GuruStron I do not think I can say that I have definitely confirmed it and I am trying to do it again now, however I get the error I pasted before to him.

Comment: Note, this happens when I call a function "GetFriends()", which I will add in the question. There are 5 calls from the UI made to 5 different controllers, Friends being one of them, they are all written the same.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I will first explain my assumption, since the fix might be very much limited to my scenario.

I have all of my DBContext used in 3 repositories. They all use async functions however they all contain awaits inside for any of the async functions used inside of them.
The issue seemed to only occur once I started using these repositories as before I was accessing the dbContext directly in the Controller. This made me consider the problems in the link, which I also posted a picture of in the question:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Even though it specified middle ware only, I assumed it was worth a chance since I couldn't figure any other problem.

Now as for the actual problem. One of my functions in the UserRepository, GetUser() is an async method, and even though the error seemed to be in the FriendRepository methods, since they were always the ones crashing, it turns out that the GetUser() function was used once in startup under AddJwtBearer without await.

I had assumed that since it had an await inside of it, it would not create a problem. I also had not noticed this was a problem since I was so focused on the other repository. My hope was that maybe I was missing something as simple as the dependency injection through a constructor in middleware switching lifetime regardless of what the lifetime was already set to.

For anyone else in the future, I ended up doing 2 things which allowed me to clearly debug my application step by step.

1. I created a Logger static class which allows me to save text to file easily. I use this to log functions being used, constructors etc. This let me ensure that I could track the amount of times constructors and functions were called, in what order and which ones would not be reached. Here is the Logger for anyone else:

   ```
   public static class Logger
   {
    public static void Log(string text, string fileName)
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "/" + fileName;

        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            done = true;

            try
            {
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.File.Exists(path) ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

                using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                {
                    fs.WriteLine(text);
                };
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                done = false;

            }

        }
    }
    public static void Log(string text)
    {
        Log(text, "logger.txt");
    }
   }
   ```
2. I added a string to the DBContext and whenever I use it in any function I would add the name of the function after the name of the class it is used in. So if my FriendsRepository would use it in a function GetTypes, it would look like:

   ```
   myDbContext.methodUsing = "FriendsRepository>GetTypes()";
   ```

Thank you to @GuruStron for being patient and giving me advice on how to take this step by step, explaining to me that the middleware error idea had no leg to stand on and suggesting to me on how to approach debugging.